# How to select this element and children of next element in one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change CSS settings on click for a headline `p` and other `p`'s located in a `div` next to the headline `p`

**The HTML structure**

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <p id="headline">My headline</p>
    <div id="listContainer">
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
        <p>Text 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current Solution**

Currently, I use jQuery's `next()`, `children()` and `addBack()` approach, but it only selects the children and is not merging it back with the headline `p` *(I assume because `addBack()` is going back to the second last child of `children` (?))*

```
$("p#headline").click(function() {
    $(this).next().children().addBack().css({"background-color": "#000", "color": "#fff"})
})
```

How can I achieve a selection of both the `children` and the headline `p` without writing a second line? (jQuery or javascript)

**EDIT**

Some of the CSS settings are based on variables' values which may change

Comment: What does writing a second line bother you? It's likely to be clearer and easier to debug.

Comment: Because the css settings are same for both (and actually a little more than the once shown in the sample code here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve a selection of both the children and the headline p without writing a second line?

You can do this:

```
$(this).next().children().add(this).css(/*...*/);
```

`addBack` didn't work because it added back the next element, not `this`.

---

But I wouldn't do that. Instead, I'd do this:

```
$(this).closest(".outerDiv").addClass("some-class-named-semantically");
```

...and have a CSS rule like:

```css
.some-class-named-semantically #headline,
.some-class-named-semantically #listContainer p {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I don't know what clicking this headline means, but for instance if it selects it, then the class name might be `selected`.

Re your edit:

> Some of the CSS settings are based on variables' values which may change

Usually that can be addressed with theming classes. But in any case, the main question you asked is answered at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: This is not working because some of my CSS settings are based on js variables (I update my question to address this)

Comment: Why would you not recommend the first approach? And if you were me, would you write a second line with same settings?

Comment: @JoeBe - I think styling and code should be separate, so that you can change the styling by just changing the CSS. Re writing the settings twice: No, I wouldn't do that. I'd either use the one-liner above, or use a couple of lines to build the jQuery set, or assign the settings object to a variable and reuse it.

Comment: I second with T.J when he doesn't recommend using `.css()` to change your CSS directly except having a good reason to do so. Because of isolating your styling with your logic code is a good concept to follow and somehow this helps easier for others to read and maintain your code later. Usually the only CSS properties would be changed is `top` and `left` or anything to do with absoluted position, most of the times you can do this part in CSS